# MonaQL で文字列の部分一致ワイルドカードは使えますか？

Tags: monaca

お世話になります。

以下コードです。

3行目overDateにワイルドカードを使って「2014/8」が含まれる（2014年8月に該当する）レコードを抽出したいのですが、どのように記述したらいいでしょうか？

```
var UserDetails = monaca.cloud.Collection('UserDetails');
var criteriaStr = 'push_flg == "1"';
criteriaStr += ' && overDate == "'+from_yyyy+'/'+from_m+'/*"';
var Criteria = monaca.cloud.Criteria(criteriaStr);
UserDetails.find( Criteria, 'User_Oid ASC', { propertyNames: ["User_Oid"] } )
  .done( function( result ) {
     // 処理
    .fail( function( error ) {
      // 対象となるユーザーIDの取得に失敗した場合はPush通知は行いません。
      alert( '対象となるユーザーの取得に失敗しました。' );
      return;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

ワイルドカードがなさそうなので、下記のメソッドみたいに作るのはどうですか。

```
var monaQuery = buildMonaQuery(2014,8);

var Criteria = monaca.cloud.Criteria(
  'overDate IN ?',
  [monaQuery]
); 

function buildMonaQuery(from_year, from_month){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 1; i<=31; i++){
        result.push(from_year + '/' + from_month + '/' + i);
    }
    return result;
}
```